# How to get "client.id" from Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, quota, clientid

The situation is the following.

Some of my sinks, which are connected to Kafka, are very sensitive on load.
They are DBs, which do do like to be overloaded.

I would like dynamically set quota values for some topics depending on overall load on those sinks. I am feeding data into DBs using Kafka Connect and self-made streamming app based on KStreams.

I know I cannot set quota on the topic, but on the client.id.
Anyhow at the end I prefer to have control over concrete topic(s).

Especially later I prefer to have a tool (perhaps self programmed) to close the the feeback loop from sink load to kafka quotas.

Even more complicated the matter is, when using streams, as client.id is extended with postfix like

```
StreamThread-1-consumer-f1835e80-e8ae-428a-a40e-2a44aab0e9ae
```

I have admin access to the topics, so I can "sniff" all messages.
The question is:

How to get client.id of the message in certain topic without asking developers, what they had implemented or if they had changed something related to client.id?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you describe the infrastructure for the sinks a little more? What are they? Databases? Applications? Another Topic? How are they consuming Kafka, via Connectors? Via Consumer API? The reason I ask, is that consumers fetch data, meaning they ask for it when they are ready, but maybe in your case their is a Connector to a sink that is not throttled correctly.